# What is link_name_to_fields_array in SugarCRM?

Tags: web-services, rest, soap, sugarcrm

Please Help me out with this..

I'm trying to get data from module using get_entries.
I'm still stuck on this array "link_name_to_fields_array"..

Can anyone explain me what it is? What kind of Data to pass in it?